# Moving users table between laravel projects

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration

I have an existing Laravel 5.5 application that is deployed and has users registered on it and using it. It also uses socialite for facebook auth, but for the sake of simplicity I want to focus on the subset of users that used the email/password registration(this system was set up using php artisan make:auth)

I want to remake this application completely, using a newer version of laravel and a whole different CI infrastructure. The problem I am having is I can not figure out how to properly migrate the users table so that existing users will still be able to log in with their passwords.

When moving between projects, what things do I have to account for so that the hashes generated with the bcrypt function will be exactly the same as the bcrypt of the old app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move them freely.  The key:generate feature is only used for Crypt::encrypt and Crypt::decrypt.  It has nothing to do with the saved passwords or Hash::make functions.